# How to convert wchar_t[] to basic_string<_Elem>?

Tags: c++

I need to convert a project from VS2003 to VS2008. In the following code:

```
wchar_t wpom[30];
mbtowc(wpom, "olaboga", 10);

ati_dom::DOMString w = wpom;
```

I get an error (on the last line): Cannot convert from 'wchar_t[30]' to 'basic_string<_Elem>').

I tried to modify it to:

```
wchar_t wpom[30];
mbtowc(wpom, "olaboga", 10);

std::basic_string<wchar_t> basic_wpom(wpom);
ati_dom::DOMString w = basic_wpom;
```

But all I acomplished is to get another error: Cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem>'

How can I convert wchar_t[] to basic_string<_Elem> and not to basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>...?

Comment: Is there any more text to that error?  Something like `_Elem = wchar_t`, or `_Elem = whatever`.  Or, can you provide a link to documention for the api you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not responding - i found out what the problem was on my own.

As it turns out, DOMString is declared like this:

```
typedef std :: basic_string< unsigned short > DOMString;
```

So simple casting to unsigned short did the trick:

```
ati_dom::DOMString w = (unsigned short *)wpom;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a std::wstring directly via the constructor that takes a pointer to the first element and the length of the array:

```
wchar_t warr[ 30 ];
// populate the array
std::wstring wstrTemp( &warr[ 0 ], 30 );
```

Comment: I don't think that's the line he's having trouble with.  `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` and `std::wstring` are the same thing.